# Wireshark plugin - dlg_utils in dissector

Tags: wireshark, wireshark-dissector

I've been trying to incorporate some GUI utils in a dissector which is being developed as a plugin for Wireshark.
The functionalities I need are the ones declared in **ui/gtk/dlg_utils.h**, specially the function **dlg_window_new**.
I have linked **libgtkui.lib** in the relevant Makefile, but this library apparently requires the linkage of many other ones. Should **libgtkui.lib** be kind of stand-alone? If it should, what is being done wrong? If it should not, which other libraries should be linked with it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've been trying to incorporate some GUI utils in a dissector

That's not supported; there is no guarantee that it will work.  (Dissectors are linked into TShark, which does not have and will not ever have a GUI, does not link with any GUI library, and is intended to be able to be built even if the target platform has no support for a GUI, just support for the command line.)

The GUI should be implemented using a tap; see `doc/README.tapping` and various taps in the `ui/gtk` source directory.